# Using lock in multiple threads with a stored copy of the lock object

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I am trying to use lock with a shared object which I pass into my worker thread. In the code below, if I pass in the syncLock object in the Execute method of Worker, everything works fine.

However, if I store a local copy of the syncLock object in my Worker class, it does not work.

Obviously when I'm doing the "_syncLock = syncLock;" assignment, instead of having a reference to the shared syncLock object, I'm getting a new object. So I end up with each thread having it's own syncLock now instead of the shared object.

Is there way to store a local reference to the shared object? I thought that an object assignment is always a "reference" in C#?

**Worker.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CacheConcurrency
{
    class Worker
    {
        int _ID;
        string _Request;
        object _syncLock;
        MyCache _TheCache;
        public Worker(int ID, string Request, ref object syncLock, ref MyCache TheCache)
        {
            _ID = ID;
            _Request = Request;
            _syncLock = syncLock;
            _TheCache = TheCache;
        }
        public void Execute()
        {
            lock (_syncLock)
            {
                if (_TheCache == null)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    _TheCache = new MyCache();
                    _TheCache.LoadCache();
                    Console.WriteLine("thread {0}: created and loaded the cache", _ID);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("thread {0}: using the existing cache", _ID);
                    Console.WriteLine("TheCache.MyCacheValue {0}", _TheCache.MyCacheValue);
                    Console.WriteLine("TheCache.CacheTimeStamp {0}", _TheCache.CacheTimeStamp);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("worker DoSomething: {0}", _Request);
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CacheConcurrency
{    
    class Main
    {
        public MyCache TheCache = null;
        public object syncLock = new object();

        public void Execute()
        {
            List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Task _Task = new Task(() => DoSomething(i, "test"));
                _Task.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("started Thread={0} at {1}", _Task.Id, DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff tt"));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit the program");
            while (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 0) ;

        }

        void DoSomething(int ID, string Request)
        {
            Worker worker = new Worker(ID, Request, ref syncLock, ref TheCache);
            worker.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

**MyCache.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CacheConcurrency
{
    class MyCache
    {
        public int MyCacheValue;
        public DateTime CacheTimeStamp;
        public MyCache()
        {
            
        }

        public void LoadCache()
        {
            MyCacheValue = 1;
            CacheTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;            
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CacheConcurrency
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Main main = new Main();
            main.Execute();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: `ref object syncLock, ref MyCache TheCache` -- Why are these two parameters by ref?

Comment: The "ref" was there to ensure the same shared object was passed in and not a copy of it. I tried removing the ref from the code and it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: There's quite a few things wrong with this _old school_ way of doing multithreaded coding.  _Unnecessary `Thread.Sleep()`; brute-force object-locking; insufficient thread safety; unrecommended use of `Task.Start()` and `ref` parameters_ which begs the _design question_ of _why would a **worker** be responsible for creating a **cache?**_.  Design concerns aside, the latter will require adequate thread safety which your code hasn't.

Comment: Your question is not very "appetizing" IMHO, because the code is split in multiple files, and it's not minimal. For example the `Execute` and `DoSomething` methods could be static methods of the `Program` class, instead of being instance methods of a (confusingly named) `Main` class. Also the `MyCache` includes an empty parameter-less constructor. Redundant code that serves only as a distraction from the main issue. You might get some answers if you minimalize your example, and remove all the distractions like the `ref` parameters.

Comment: Also I would suggest to state explicitly inside the question what's the observed/actual behavior of your example, and how it defers from the expected behavior.

Comment: @MickyD Thank you for the extensive feedback, much appreciated! I created that trivial example to loosely mimic some code we have in production which is experiencing this issue. The actual prod code has a TCP listener which is firing off threads, which would be too complex to include in here. I thought using a task would be the closest possible idea. Any idea on what particular thread-safety changes are required here?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks! Please see my comment to MickyD, the idea was to loosely mimic some existing code we inherited. I will see if I can improve the code example to make it more "appetizing" as you say!

Comment: You're also not capturing the variable `i` so the value passed thru isn't always the current value of `i`.

Comment: "Obviously when I'm doing the "_syncLock = syncLock;" assignment, instead of having a reference to the shared syncLock object, I'm getting a new object. So I end up with each thread having it's own syncLock now instead of the shared object." - No, that's not true. The code `_syncLock = syncLock;` just copies a reference to the same object. Copies are not being made.

Comment: @Enigmativity, "Copies are not being made" - that's what I thought too. But otherwise how would you explain things working correctly when passing the synlock object in to the Execute method, and not working when storing the reference in _syncLock?

Comment: @johnivers - If you have two versions of your code - one that works and one that doesn't - then clearly show both versions - AND explain what's working and what's not. That's the quickest way to get an answer. Good questions on this site get answers in minutes. If you improve the quality you'll get an answer.

Comment: _"The actual prod code has a **TCP listener** which is **firing off threads**"_ - well that's quite possibly another problem - spinning-up threads for I/O bound code is kinda a waste of a thread (and doesn't scale terribly well) as it will spend most of its time blocked/waiting for the I/O to complete.   Consider using modern `async/await` with TCP xxxAsync() methods (e.g. Read) as they will make use of async I/O via I/O Completion Ports where [There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out the problem, thanks for the comments who got me on the right track. In particular, thanks to MickyD who commented on the code needing to be thread-safe which led me to the answer.

It turns out that I was protecting with lock correctly in my Execute function, however in my constructor I was still referencing the shared Cache object without a lock, which was not thread-safe and causing a race condition.

The fix is to put both the constructor call and the Execute inside the critical section/lock block like so:

```
void DoSomething(int ID, string Request)
{
    lock(syncLock) 
    {
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        worker.Execute(ID, Request, ref TheCache);
    }
}
```

This also simplifies the worker code, avoiding the need to store a local reference of the syncLock object and doing a lock in there.

I also agree with MickyD's other comments that this code should be re-written to use async/await, not have a cache inside the worker etc. The longevity of us using this code base is in question, so investing in the tech debt is uncertain at the moment.

Comment: Why `ref TheCache` rather than `TheCache`? You don't seem to be updating the cache.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, ref can indeed be dropped here. It was in the original code we inherited so I left it in the example.